# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error when trying to use a local variable?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

Here is my code. It's supposed to take in two strings and compare their differences character by character.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Positions {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String first = scan.next();
  String second = scan.next();
  if(first.length()>second.length()){
     int length = first.length();
  }else{
     int length = second.length();
  }
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
     if(first.charAt(i)!=second.charAt(i)){
        System.out.print(i+" "+first.charAt(i)+" "+second.charAt(i));
     }
  }
 }
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to compile:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Positions.java
Positions.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
      for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
                       ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: class Positions
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Google "variable scope".

Comment: Candidate duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 7):

Your `length` variable is declared and initialized in each case of `if` and `else` and then immediately discarded as out of scope when the block ends.

Declare it before the `if` and initialize it in each case, so it remains in scope for the `for` loop further down.

```
int length;
if(first.length()>second.length()){
   length = first.length();
}else{
   length = second.length();
}
```